# Rebuild solution in vs2008 without visual studio?

Tags: asp.net

How can we Rebuild solution in vs2008 without visual studio?

Comment: What is your exact requirement...?

Comment: How to rebuild in Visual Studio without Visual Studio? - Does not compute!

Comment: If you can use Visual Studio Express edition, that would work.  It should be possible to compile it on the command line also.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understand the question, but you can run [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452.aspx) from the command line to rebuild most projects in a solution.

```
MSBuild.exe Path\To\Solution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

If you don't run from the Visual Studio command prompt, you can find MSBuild.exe for .NET 3.5 under

- `%FrameworkDir%\%Framework35Version%` or
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5`

Comment: +1, you can invoke MSBuild directly on any project file, although you might have to make a customised MSBuild targets file or project file to replace the solution file. MSBuild is part of the .Net framework, so no VS is required.